# How to print a square in c++

Tags: c++, square

I want to make a function to print square like the following output.
user enter the side of square (N). The total length of N is must an odd.

```
int main()
{
    int n, i, j;
    cin >> n;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            if (i == 1 || i == n || j == 1 || j == n || i == j || i + j - 1 == n)
                cout << "#";
            else
                cout << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

the expected output for n = 7 :

```
#######
##   ##
# # ###
#  ####
# # ###
##   ##
#######
```

the expected output for n = 9 :

```
#########
##     ##
# #   ###
#  # ####
#   #####
#  # ####
# #   ###
##     ##
#########
```

And here is my actual output (n = 9) :

```
#########
##     ##
# #   # #
#  # #  #
#   #   #
#  # #  #
# #   # #
##     ##
#########
```

but I can't add the # on the right side.

Comment: Try `i + j - 1 >= n` instead of `i + j - 1 == n`

Comment: The diagonal is `i(j) = j` and counter-diagonal is `i(j) = n - j + 1`. The right half planes are `i(j) < j` and `i(j) > n - j + 1`. Print a `#` if a point is in both half-planes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `|| i <= j && i + j - 1 >= n`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    

    int n, i, j;
    cin >> n;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            if (i == 1 || i == n || j == 1 || j == n || i == j || i + j - 1 == n || i <= j && i + j - 1 >= n)
                cout << "#";
            else
                cout << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/yooasE)

Answer (score 3):

You've written the conditions for every scenario (first/last line, first/last column, primary/secondary diagonal). Now you need to add the condition for that right triangle.

Hint: there is an easy condition for this triangle:

```
      #
     ##
    ###
   ####
  #####
 ######
#######
```

and there is an easy condition for this triangle:

```
#######
 ######
  #####
   ####
    ###
     ##
      #
```

And the triangle you want is the intersection between these two.